# Ежесекундное появление изображений

Tags: html, javascript

Как на JS сделать так, чтобы после загрузки страницы начали появляться попарно картинки? Через секунду - вторая пара, через следующую секунду - третья, и т.д.

Comment: Сесть и написать=) Если у тебя с этим совсем туго - гугли всякие фотогалереи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var min = 0;
var max = 8;
var arrbnr = new Array(max);
setInterval(function()
{
  for(i = min; i < max; i++) {
  var banner = document.getElementById('Banner');
  banner.src = arrbnr[i];
}
//запускает ротацию!
if(min < max)
{
  min++;
}
//повторяем снова
if(min >= max)
{
    arrbnr[min=0];
    banner.src = '1.jpg';
}
}, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="Banner" src="1.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Где то в этом направлении. Докрутить и будет работать!

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() в котором бы колбэком была бы таже самая функция.

Answer (score 0):

Плагин **Slider Kit** к jquery (kyrielles.net/sliderkit) вполне удобен. Пример на сайте [Алтай-парк](http://altai-park.ru/)